# How to identify newline character in editText text?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I am getting text from a multiline edit text. I need to identify newline character in this text. How to do it?

```
s.toString().contains("\\n")
```

returns false.

Comment: what is s? presumably not the control itself?

Comment: @SanjayManohar s is editable of the control

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a typo. It should be:

```
s.toString().contains("\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

try as:

```
for(int i=0; i<-s.toString().length()-1; i++)
{
if(s.toString().charAt(i)=='\\n') 
    { 
      Log.i("NEW LINE?", "NEW LINE");
    }

}
```

or `use .contains("\n")` as

```
if(s.toString().contains("\n")==true)
{
Log.i("NEW LINE?", "NEW LINE");
}
else
{
Log.i("NOT NEW LINE", "NOT NEW LINE");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually do it by defining a KeyListener on the EditText.

Whenever you detect a newline character, you can do whatever you want to do in your code.

```
userIdInput.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)  {

           // the enter key has been pressed. Do whatever you want to!

            }
            return false;

        }

    });
```

**NOTE :** return **true** if you want to tell the OS that you have handled the event, otherwise return **false**.
(But given your scenario, I guess you would want to return false)